# Restart image sequence for each new particle?

Tags: particles, image

I have a plane, with an animated image sequence as a material. I then have the object (below) as an emitter, emitting these planes as particles. The image sequence is a cyclic texture, so that it repeats again and again.

In short, rather than having the texture the same for every single plane, as it is below, how can I have it start again for every new particle as it appears?

[image]

Comment: What is your experience with Python?  Answers might be ... experience .. 1 month .. 2 months ... 4 months

Comment: Which version of Blender?  Which renderer Blender, Cycles, or other?

Comment: I'm afraid I have little or no experience with Python :(. I'm using Cycles. And also, I can't just use a group. The particular image sequence begins as a swirl (in the pic above) and then rotates, and then fades out, but it's all done in the image. I don't want a separate object for each different kind of particle, unless I can change the object, while keeping the rotation / location bla bla bla...

Comment: Have you ever used a group?  Have you tested with a group?

Comment: What you wrote in the comment is not clear to me and has a bit of sluggish flavor. My experiences would tell me you would improve your variety by the proposed answer below. The particular image sequence importance is not clear. Your wrote [location bla bla bla] which does not sound of clarity or energy. Maybe some rest will restore your ThunderBolt832.

Comment: Sorry, I had another look at your answer, and it suits what I wanted. Sorry for not being clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender Particles has both an object and group feature.  You appear to already be using the object feature. With a bit of practice new particles can be added in 88 seconds or less.  We happen to show Materials and Texture for Blender Internal Render.  Cycles has a similar settings in the nodes.

[image]

Particle System panel showing location of group information.  Also showing some groups in the outliner window. Image above.

[image]

Material/Texture/Image Sequence/Offset and Start. Image Above.

Here is a video tutorial for creating a group.  It may or may not be the same version of Blender you are using.  You may choose a different tutorial on the topic of [groups]. I just did a quick search.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2Q6KcSho48

or the manual

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/groups.html

One way to achieve your goal is to create a [group] of particles.

- Each plane in the group can be different. Blender can use any of the planes in the group. This feature is in the particle settings use group. See image above.  I suggest you put at least 9 image planes in your group for variety.
- This proposed answer does not use Python. If the OP has Python experience then the OP can do some of these tasks with Python.
- The planes in the group will be different because you will take the steps to have different [start and offset and image selection quantity] values for them into the image sequence.
- A suggestion is to create another plane as a duplicate of what you already have, then change the [start and offset].  The offset is within the image texture settings.  See image above.  Change to suit your needs.
- If the original plane is in the group, then all duplicates will also be in the group.
- Please verify and improve these suggestions and suit to your needs.